# Differential of integrating factor $d(e^{at}r_t)$ in Vasicek model

Tags: itos-lemma, sde, vasicek

I am attempting to solve the Vasicek model SDE (using [Wikipedia parametrisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasicek_model)):

$$
dr_t = a(b-r_t)dt + \sigma dW_t
$$

Every solution is proceeding to multiply both sides of the equation by the integrating factor $e^{at}$ (akin to solving linear ODEs). After multiplication and rearrangement we get the following equation:

$$
e^{at}dr_t + e^{at}ar_tdt= e^{at}(abdt + \sigma dW_t)
$$
Now the left hand side is apparently equal to $d(e^{at}r_t)$. How is that exactly the case?

Is it by [Ito product rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997889/product-rule-for-ito-processes)? If so what is $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$?

Is it by Ito's lemma but then what is the $f(x,t)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply the Ito product rule, noting the cov of a deterministic and stochastic term is zero:

$$\begin{align}
d\left(e^{at}r_t\right)&=e^{at} dr_t+r_t de^{at}
\\[6pt]
&=e^{at} dr_t+r_t e^{at} d(at)
\\[6pt]
&=e^{at} dr_t+r_t e^{at} a dt
\end{align}$$

Comment: By the "cov of a deterministic and stochastic term" do you mean $dr_tde^{at}$ from Ito's Product rule which when we multiply out and substitute for $dr_t$ we get  $[a(b-r_t)dt + \sigma dW_t]de^{at}$ and hence we only get the $dtdt$ and $dtdW_t$ terms which are all 0?

Comment: That’s right! Though this result can be generalised